# How to merge cvs branch to head from command line?

Tags: version-control, merge, branch, cvs

I have a script to merge one branch to other and I am using below commands in the script. I am passing input as trunk name, working branch, source branch

How can I modify these commands if I have to merge branch to HEAD(trunk)?

```
cvs -d $cvs_root update -j$working_branch -j $source_branch

cvs -d $cvs_root commit -m "Merging ${source_branch} branch to ${working_branch} branch"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've tried "HEAD" and it doesn't work?

I've found with CVS, I never quite know if a command will interpret `HEAD` as "main trunk" or more rarely as "tip the current branch".

As a workaround, you could always tag HEAD and then use the tag.